# husky pre-commit hook not working after adding it to package.json

Tags: javascript, git, mocha.js, husky

I am working on a project and I want that every time I try to commit a new change, my tests are run and based on that it is decided whether the commit would happen. For this to happen I researched and found I can use [husky's pre-commit hook](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-commit-hooks-to-git-with-husky-to-automate-code-tasks/#step-0-setting-up-a-new-project).

I first installed husky in my project with
`npm i husky --save-dev`
which installed `"husky": "^6.0.0"` in my `package.json`.

Then I followed the tutorial and added the following object in `package.json`

```
 "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "applypatch-msg": "echo \"[Husky] applypatch-msg\"",
      "pre-applypatch": "echo \"[Husky] pre-applypatch\"",
      "post-applypatch": "echo \"[Husky] post-applypatch\"",
      "pre-commit": "echo \"[Husky] pre-commit\""
    }
  }
```

As you can see, running `git commit -m "some message!"` should echo bunch of stuff which would mean that husky's pre-commit hook is working but instead nothing of the sort gets echoed. Now I have just no clue why is that not working. If it had worked I would have went on to add script in pre-commit hook to run my tests.

Here is the `package.json` file by the way:

```
{
  "name": "test app",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "test app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": nodemon index.js",
    "test": "find ./plugins -name '*test.js' | xargs mocha -R spec"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/boom": "^9.0.0",
    "@hapi/glue": "^7.0.0",
    "@hapi/good": "^9.0.0",
    "@hapi/good-console": "^9.0.0",
    "@hapi/good-squeeze": "^6.0.0",
    "@hapi/hapi": "^19.1.1",
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "base-64": "0.1.0",
    "confit": "2.3.0",
    "hapi-auth-jwt2": "^8.8.1",
    "hapi-mongodb": "^9.0.0",
    "jws": "4.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.7",
    "pad-left": "2.1.0",
    "pino": "^5.16.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.1",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "selectn": "^1.1.2",
    "superagent": "3.8.2",
    "utf8": "^3.0.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-datetime": "^1.6.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.0.0",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "mocha": "^5.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "proxyquire": "^2.0.1",
    "sinon": "^5.0.10",
    "sinon-test": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "applypatch-msg": "echo \"[Husky] applypatch-msg\"",
      "pre-applypatch": "echo \"[Husky] pre-applypatch\"",
      "post-applypatch": "echo \"[Husky] post-applypatch\"",
      "pre-commit": "echo \"[Husky] pre-commit\""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well I still couldn't make it work but I did found that with husky v6, we don't add hooks like this i the package.json file anymore. However downgrading husky to version 4 didn't make it work either. Why?

Comment: I know very little about Husky itself, but: which of these various steps installed files in `.git/hooks/` in your repository? Check that there is at least one executable Git hook, e.g., that `.git/hooks/pre-commit` exists and is executble.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old but maybe my solution will help someone.

It didn't work for me either to use this technique. The cleanest I found is

add script to package json:

```
"prepare": ""chmod ug+x ./installHooks.sh && ./installHooks.sh""
```

with installHooks.sh containing:

```
#!/bin/zsh
FILE=.husky
if test -d "$FILE"; then
  echo "$FILE folder already exists, deleting it before new husky installation";
  rm -rf "./$FILE"
  # else echo "$FILE doesn't exist yet";
fi
  cd ../ && husky install ./sub-project/.husky
  cd sub-project && npx husky add .husky/pre-commit 'cd sub-project && npm test'
  chmod ug+x ./.husky/*
  echo "hooks correctly installed. you may find them in `.husky/pre-commit`"
  echo "they will be triggered each time you commit"
```

**Explanation**:
The prepare script will be ran automatically when running `npm install` or can be ran with `npm run prepare`
It will change the mode of installHooks.sh to executable then run it.
installHooks will check if the .husky folder already exists, delete it if it's the case, then install husky (note that going up one folder then down in sub-project is because my git repo contains several sub projects and I want to install this in the front-end one, here called sub-project. husky requires that you install it from the root so this is a workaround). Then adding pre-commit hook (npm test) Finally make husky hooks executable with chmod

Let me know if you have questions. I'm just starting writing scripts so this might not be the optimal way of doing this but it works

Comment: I had difficulty getting this to work, but I got it done as follows. I put my pre-commit hook in file `.husky/pre-commit`. Then I put in `package.json` a script named `prepare`  with the code `npx husky install`. This prepare script is called automatically when `yarn install` is executed.